# Better way to merge two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am trying make this code run a bit more functional.

I want to filter a set of data according to a selection of names in `list`, then based on the `ReportsTo` for each person I am recursively finding their line managers but only if the `Rank` is greater than 3.

This works, but is there a better more concise way to achieve the same result?

```js
const data = [
  {
    Name: 'Peter',
    ReportsTo: '',
    Rank: 1
  },
  {
    Name: 'Tom',
    ReportsTo: 'Peter',
    Rank: 2
  },
  {
    Name: 'Maria',
    ReportsTo: 'Tom',
    Rank: 3
  },
  {
    Name: 'Liam',
    ReportsTo: 'Maria',
    Rank: 4
  },
  {
    Name: 'John',
    ReportsTo: 'Peter',
    Rank: 3
  },
  {
    Name: 'Fiona',
    ReportsTo: 'Liam',
    Rank: 5
  }
]

// Start with only these names
const list = ['Fiona', 'Tom']
const filtered = data.filter(({Name}) => list.includes(Name))

// Recursively find the missing managers of the list names if the rank is not below 3
const findManager = (manager) => {
  const next = data.find(({ Name}) => Name === manager)
  return next.Rank > 3
   ? [next, ...findManager(next.ReportsTo)]
   : [next]
}

// Check the line managers for the filtered array and store them
const missingManagers = []
for (const { ReportsTo, Rank} of filtered) {
  if(!list.includes(ReportsTo) && Rank > 3) {
    missingManagers.push(...findManager(ReportsTo))
  }
}

// Merge the missing managers with the filtered list
const result = [...missingManagers, ...filtered]

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, but still not sure if it is a better aproach

```
const result = filtered.reduce((total, current) => {
  if(!list.includes(current.ReportsTo) && current.Rank > 3) {
    total.push(
      current,
      ...findManager(current.ReportsTo)
    )
  } else total.push(current)
  
  return total

}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

First, note that [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) have different purposes.

It's a bit confusing, but if I've understood, you wanna extract people that are managers and all the people who has Rank > 4 (manager or not)?

```js
const data = [
  {
    Name: "Peter",
    ReportsTo: "",
    Rank: 1,
  },
  {
    Name: "Tom",
    ReportsTo: "Peter",
    Rank: 2,
  },
  {
    Name: "Maria",
    ReportsTo: "Tom",
    Rank: 3,
  },
  {
    Name: "Liam",
    ReportsTo: "Maria",
    Rank: 4,
  },
  {
    Name: "John",
    ReportsTo: "Peter",
    Rank: 3,
  },
  {
    Name: "Fiona",
    ReportsTo: "Liam",
    Rank: 5,
  },
];

const managers = [];

data.forEach((element) => {
  if (element.ReportsTo && !managers.includes(element.ReportsTo)) {
    managers.push(element.ReportsTo);
  }
});
const filtered = data.filter((element) => {
  if (managers.includes(element.Name) || managers.includes(element.ReportsTo) || element.Rank > 3) return element;
  return false;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: No, what I want to do is what the code snippet does, I was just wondering if I could do it with out the for loop and just mapping over the filter array

Comment: Man... sorry but the code is a mess. What's your main goal? which elements you want to filter? what are the requisites?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
getLineManagersAboveRankThree() {
    return data.filter(person => person.Rank >= 3 &&
                                 data.some(({ReportsTo}) => ReportsTo === person.Name)
                      );
}
```

Method `some` will return `true` when any one of the elements in the collection fulfill the condition. So you can check in the `data` list for people that are someones line managers.

This is a little expensive time-complexity wise but is straightforward based on the requirement.